# How to pass a GridView column values to a List<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, webforms

I tried something like this:

```
double[] listArray = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[k].Cells[1].Text) };
```

than pass this to an array:

```
 var num = new List<double>();
                    num.AddRange(listArray);
                    num.Sort();
```

I only want to pass gridView column values to a List<>  than rank it.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare list then you can simply run a for loop on all rows and just add this particular column value to the list. an then apply the Sort method.

something like this.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>(YouRowCount);
foreach (var row in youRows)
    ids.Add((int)row["id"]); //or access by column index
```